# How many eggs is acceptable to be eaten for a day?

Tags: cholesterol, eggs

How many eggs is acceptable to be eaten for a day?

Note: I have a little bit of extra cholesterol.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can eat as many eggs as you want, as long as you eat other kinds of food as well to balance out your diet. Here's why:

- Eggs contain a substantial amount of cholesterol. However, [as you can read here](http://www.unisci.com/stories/20014/1029013.htm), a substance called lecithin in the eggs inhibits the absorption of cholesterol, so most of the cholesterol in the egg will not be taken up by your body.
- Actually, [eating eggs will increase only "good" HDL cholesterol, and has no effect on "bad" LDL cholesterol](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18575296).
- Also, [this study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17092383) explicitly states that people who eat lots of eggs are less likely to have elevated cholesterol.
- [Here's yet another study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20598142) which says that eating eggs will not increase cholesterol or risk for heart disease. [And here's another one.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11023007) [Here's a review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15640512) which comes to the same conclusion.

I could give you more studies, but I think you get the point. The notion that eggs are bad for your cholesterol is **simply false**.

**Conclusion: Eat all the eggs you want!**

Comment: Cypher has given you **perfect advice**.  In general, people never listen to good advice.  So, I urge you to read the book mentioned below!  Buy a copy immediately.

Comment: Side note on eating all the eggs you want:  The egg yolk contains the bulk of the egg's calories (yolk = 55 calories, white = 15 cals.) If you are looking for a good source of protein, but watching your calories, you can eat more egg whites without the higher caloric yolk.  However, whole eggs (including the yolk) give you lots of other good nutrients, so you wouldn't want to exclude all yolks.  [This article](http://www.eggnutritioncenter.org/blog/2011/01/25/whole-eggs-vs-egg-whites/) includes a chart that compares nutrients of the whole egg vrs. just the egg white.